# React/Redux - How to invoke a second function in componentDidMount after the first one finishes fetching AJAX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, axios

I have this React-Native app, which fetches a list of items, and then, an image gallery for each of those items. So basically, I have two ajax function, and the second one needs the list of items fetched in the first function.
I make the first invoke in componentDidMount(), but I don't know how to "wait" for it to finish to make the second call. If I just place them one after the other, the second one won't do anything because there is no list of items yet.
How can I solve this? I read similar questions here on StackOverflow but couldn't find a clear example for this case. Also, in the code, I commented some of my unsuccessful tries.

Thanks in advance, I'm new to React so I can be missing something simple.

component.js

```
class EtiquetasList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.FetchEtiquetas();
    if ( this.props.etiquetas.length > 0 ) { // I tried this but didn't do anything
      this.props.FetchGalleries( this.props.etiquetas );
    }
  }

  renderEtiquetas() {
      if ( this.props.galleries.length > 0 ) {
        // if I invoke FetchGalleries here, it works, but loops indefinitely
        return this.props.etiquetas.map(etiqueta =>
          <EtiquetaDetail key={etiqueta.id} etiqueta={etiqueta} galleries={ this.props.galleries } />
        );
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        { this.renderEtiquetas() }
      </ScrollView>
    );

  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    etiquetas: state.data.etiquetas,
    isMounted: state.data.isMounted,
    galleries: state.slides.entries
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { FetchEtiquetas, FetchGalleries })(EtiquetasList);
```

actions.js

```
export function FetchEtiquetas() {
  return function (dispatch) {
      axios.get( url )
        .then(response => {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })

        }
      );
  }
}

export function FetchGalleries( etiquetas ) {

    return function (dispatch) {
        return Promise.all(
          etiquetas.map( record =>
            axios.get('https://e.dgyd.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/media?_embed&parent='+record.id)
        )).then(galleries => {

          let curated_data = [];
          let data_json = '';

          galleries.map( record => {
            record.data.map( subrecord => {
              // this is simplified for this example, it works as intended
              data_json = data_json + '{ title: "' + subrecord.title+'"}';
          });

        my_data.push( data_json );

      });

          return dispatch({ type: FETCH_GALLERIES_SUCCESS, payload: curated_data });

        });
    }

}
```

reducer.js

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, etiquetas: action.payload, isMounted: true }; // I think it ran faster like this tho
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: You must have some sort of callback that is being invoked after your API call has returned

Comment: @klugjo I just added my Action and Reducer to the question to provide more context.

Comment: What is your `FetchGalleries` function`?

Comment: @Colliot just added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if(nextProps.etiquetas.length !== 0 && this.props.etiquetas.length === 0) {
   this.props.FetchGalleries( nextProps.etiquetas );
 }
}
```

I think componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle can do the job easily. You should use componentWillReceiveProps whenever you need to trigger something in update phase of react components

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same as when I tried to run the fetchGalleries in the render function. It keeps looping forever.
Everything renders fine, but the console.logs keep running in the console

Comment: what is the value for etiquetas in initialstate?

Comment: An empty array

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  etiquetas: [],
  isMounted: false
};

Comment: thank you! this did the trick. The other answers are interesting and I will try them too, but this is the answer to the question. Thanks again!

Comment: What if you want to refetch the etiquetas?

Comment: Then you again dispatch the request, you can add isFetching or isFetched variables for comparison. Its a general concept , so i will not extend on it

Answer (score 2):

You may try modifying your "Fetch" functions to return the Promise object. Then you can chain them togather like this:

```
export function FetchEtiquetas() {
  return function (dispatch) {
      return axios.get( url ).then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data }) 
      })
  }
}
```

Invoke in "componentDidMount":

```
this.props.FetchEtiquetas().then(() => {
  this.props.FetchGalleries( this.props.etiquetas );
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume you are using `redux-thunk`.

I suggest combining them together to an action creator like this (which is possible in `redux-thunk`):

```
export function FetchEtiquetasThenGalleries() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
        const etiquetas = response.data; // Assuming response.data is that array.
        return Promise.all(
          etiquetas.map(record =>
            axios.get('https://e.dgyd.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/media?_embed&parent=' + record.id)
          )).then(galleries => {

            let curated_data = [];
            let data_json = '';

            galleries.map(record => {
              record.data.map(subrecord => {
                // this is simplified for this example, it works as intended
                data_json = data_json + '{ title: "' + subrecord.title + '"}';
              });

              my_data.push(data_json);

            });

            dispatch({ type: FETCH_GALLERIES_SUCCESS, payload: curated_data });
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I'm using Redux-thunk. I just added fetchGalleries() to my code above. This sounds like a good idea. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I marked this Question as resolved by one of the other answers, but this looks very good and I'll try it anyway. Thank you very much for your rime and answer!

Answer (score 0):

To chain your actions, I would recommend chaining Promise or using async/await if you can.
To do it with Promises, you should return the `Promise` returned by the request in the action.

```
export function FetchEtiquetas() {
  return function (dispatch) {
      return axios.get( url )
        .then(response => {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })

        }
      );
  }
}
```

And use `mapDispatchToProps` on redux `connect` call, it should look like

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
     fetchData: () => {
         dispatch(FetchEtiquetas)
         .then((results) => {
             dispatch(FetchGalleries(results))
         });
      }
    }
}
```

Then in your component, just call the right prop in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this one too. On your code, on FetchEtiquetas(), should I invoke FetchGalleries() after the dispatch? or it runs in mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: I marked this Question as resolved by one of the other answers, but this looks very good and I'll try it anyway. Thank you very much for your rime and answer!

Comment: @kilinkis Actually, my answer was totally wrong your issue was more a react lifecycle question